# How to do checks in your checkbox correctly in order using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, bootstrap-4

I have 3 checkbox and want to do an order to them regarding their checks. It must first do one each of them as download, of which my logic does that, problem i have. the first function loads first and ignores others. So i want to find a way to create an order to each one of them when they are being checked so it may provide meaning to a user. Here is my logic below in both HTML and Jquery.

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class ="custom-control-input" id="temperature">
    <label class = "custom-control-label" for="temperature">Temperature</label>
  </div>

      <div class = "custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type = "checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="illuminance">
        <label class = "custom-control-label" for = "illuminance">Illuminance</label>
      <div class="form-group"><br>

    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class ="custom-control-input" id="button-state">
        <label class = "custom-control-label" for="button-state">Button-State</label>
      </div>

        <div class="col-md-1.9 text-center">
          <button id="download" name="download" class="btn btn-warning" >Download</button><br>


       // checking for per number of entries to read.
      /* $(function() {
      $("#download").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      if($('#temperature').is(':checked')) {
        window.open('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/899906/fields/1.csv?results=10');
          }
      if($('#illuminance').is(':checked')){
        window.open('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/899906/fields/2.csv?results=10');
          }
      if($('#button-state').is(':checked')){
        window.open('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/899906/fields/8.csv?results=10');
          }

        });
      });

 //checking for multiple entries to read.  
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#download").click(function() {
      var count = 0;
      if($('#temperature,#illuminance').prop('checked')) count++;
      //if($('#illuminance').prop('checked')) count++;
      // if($('#button-state').prop('checked')) count++;
      if(count > 1){
        window.open('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/899906/feeds/last.json?api_key=F35GLOFJ8L99D0OM, "blank"');
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this javascript code, hope it would be useful for you:

```
$(function() {
        $("#download").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var files = Array();
            files['temperature'] = 'https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/899906/fields/1.csv?results=10';
            files['illuminance'] = 'https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/899906/fields/2.csv?results=10';
            files['button-state'] = 'https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/899906/fields/8.csv?results=10';

            var i = 1;
            $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                if($(this).is(':checked')){
                    var id = $(this).attr('id');
                    setTimeout(function(){

                        var a = document.createElement("a");
                          a.setAttribute('href', files[id]);
                          a.setAttribute('download', '');
                          a.click();
                    }, i * 1500);
                    i++;
                }
            });

        });
    });
```

Comment: Mastafa, checking see to work for each fine, Is there way when those 2 checbox are both selected, must be able to download just one file format not 2. that what is doing currently. Especially when selecting 2. I hope make sense mate.

Comment: If you need to download just one file, you should compress the two files on the fly and download the result .zip file. This cannot be done from the client side .. only server side.

Comment: the url api, can do that stuff. I want to know when you select 2 it must allow that URL api to download. given from the above code.

Comment: The example you gave is having static files urls, you will need to read more from the API documentations to know how to send a compress request and download the result file.